# No psi shortly after kegging

Tags: kegging

I kegged my APA tonight and all seemed fine.  I set the psi to 15, burped the keg a few times and put the keg in my fridge.  An hour later I checked on it and the psi was at 0, the co2 tank was covered in frost, there is seemingly no pressure coming from the co2 tank and no excess air in the keg (when I burp it nothing happens).  The temperature in my fridge is 33 f, a little on the cold side I know but it shouldn't matter right?

I had my tank filled up a couple of weeks ago and haven't touched it since.

Did the temperature in my fridge do something (make me lose all my co2 or break some of my equipment)?
Should I Assume that my tank didn't have as much co2 as I thought it had? It's 20oz so I would have thought it would be enough for a few keggings assuming it was full.

Any suggestions as to what is going on?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you hear gas going into the keg when you finally put it away (before you discovered that the tank was out of pressure)?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you put the co2 in the fridge with the keg? Either way the c02 in your cylinder is in a liquid state (only because it's under pressure) naturally c02 turns to a gaseous state at -78c so when you are carbonating you release a fair amount of this cold liquid through the valves and regulator which starts building up "frost" ( lets keep it simple) when it builds up it becomes more constricted and eventually plugs completely, this happens to me with my propane camping stove sometimes as well. my advice would be try a slower force carb but 15 psi isnt fast, the fridge doesn't help because its cold too. I know its expensive but save up for a standard 5lb tank, it's worth it! there is also a possibility you have a large leak ( maybe you twisted something on accident) warm it up and see if there is anything left. good luck keep us posted

Comment: The frost on the tank would point to this.  I agree that a 20oz tank is sub-optimal (to be kind ;) ) for force carbonation.  I like my 20lb tank because I'm too lazy to get it filled often.